# MySQL combines results multiple results values into 2 only

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to combine values like if 0 then is the first value and if 1, 2 or 3 then it is second value

```
id   student   IQ
1    one       0
2    two       1
3    three     2
4    four      3
5    five      0
```

What I want is to tell me I have 2 student with `IQ=0` and 3 students are `> 0`

What is the easiest way to write this mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IQ = 0 THEN 1 
              WHEN IQ > 0 THEN 2
         END,
         COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN IQ = 0 THEN 1 
              WHEN IQ > 0 THEN 2
         END
```

or, if `IQ` is a positive number:

```
SELECT IF(IQ = 0, IQ, 1),
       COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY IF(IQ = 0, IQ, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(iq = 0), sum(iq > 0)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN iq = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as studentsWithZeroIq,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN iq > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as studentsWithNonZeroIq
FROM mytable;
```